# Simplify NAND circuit

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, nand

I would like to know is this can be done.

[image]

Comment: (A'.B)' is not equal to A.B'

Comment: Logic Friday is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

U18 in the third cell is an inverter. This means it inverts the complete product signal coming into it.

What you have done is inverted the components of that product, rather than inverting the whole product.

Comment: So it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the input to an inverter is A'.B the output is (A'.B)' and not A.B'